# Run Liquibase with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, liquibase

I just started automated database migrations using Liquibase. I understand the basics of Liquibase and I am able to run it using the command prompt. I want to automate this process also. I want Liquibase to run whenever my NodeJS project starts. Any Help?

Answer (score 5):

With [`node-liquibase`](https://github.com/pablodenadai/node-liquibase), you can do this already.

```
const liquibase = require('liquibase');

liquibase({
  changeLogFile: 'resources/liquibase/db.changelog.xml',
  url: 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres',
  username: 'postgres',
  password: 'admin'
})
.run('<action>', '<action-params>')
.then(() => console.log('success'))
.catch((err) => console.log('fail', err));
```

Comment: It doesn't appear to provide the liquibase jar :( do I need to version control that?

Comment: FYI with latest version, call update instead of run, but this got me unblocked. Thank you!